# Read local file in phonegap android application

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my phonegap android application, i have an xml file in assets/www/ folder.How can i read the content of this file in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this library http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/ which converts the xml data into json which can be easily used.

This function will load the xml file:

```
function readXml(){
        $.get('data.xml', function(xml){

            // converts received XML document to string
            var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
            console.log(xmlText);

            var employees = $.xml2json(xml);
            console.log(employees)
            alert(employees.employee[0].name);
        });
    }
```

Full source - https://gist.github.com/3106218

Tested this with Cordova 1.7 and Android 2.2

Comment: Thanks for response. But i don't want to convert to json. I just want the xml content or you can consider any text file instead. So how to read that? Any way?

Comment: the above function reads any file, once data available then i initiate the xml to json conversion

Comment: $.get('metadata.xml', function(xml){
        console.log(xml.toString());
      });  This prints [Object Document] but i want entire xml content as string. How to get string out of this object?